# Invisible components still take up space

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I have this one activity that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I70b2.jpg

As you can see, it has a button, a list and a button.

If certain conditions are met, I want to hide both buttons just show the list, but as you can see in the next image, the buttons are still taking up space:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dSha.jpg

So my question, what can I do to enlarge the list to take that space out?

Here is my layout for the buttons and the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="registrarAsistencia"
        android:text="Registrar Asistencia" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaAlumnos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="376dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.29" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChecarBoxes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="seleccionarTodosNinguno"
        android:text="Seleccionar / Deseleccionar todo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here it is the layout for the list's contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:textSize="16sp" 
          android:textStyle="bold"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/rowTextView2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:textSize="16sp" 
          android:textStyle="italic"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/CheckBox01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:padding="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Do not make the buttons `View.INVISIBLE`. Make the buttons `View.GONE`. There are three visibility states:

- visible (normal)
- invisible (pixels not drawn, but still takes up space)
- gone (not included in rendering)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much for the fast answer!

Answer (score 3):

In the java code

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and in the XML  code

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Thier are 3 state

1. visible: normal
2. invisible : takes space and invisible
3. gone : no space and no visibility

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

In addition to @CommonsWare's answer

You should use a layout that fits well in all screen sizes. If you give you layout a fixed height like `android:layout_height="376dp"` it will look good only on the device (or emulator) you're testing on. What you have to do is to make sure that your listview takes up all (and only) the space left by your buttons.

Check out this [article](http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) to better understand layout weights.

Comment: Im really a beginner with Android, so, mind explaining why 0dp and 1 instead of match_parent and/or wrap_content?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Moko I've just updated my answer with more information. I hope it helps.

Comment: Got it, will take a look at those. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

for hiding your widget

```
   yourEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

for visbility of your widget

```
   yourEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```